# DataStage Job stucks with warnings

Tags: datastage

i am trying to stage a dataset from source to my server, When I run my job in DataStage, It keeps stucked with no errors.
All I see is a warning which says:
When checking operator: When binding output interface field "DRIVERS" to field "DRIVERS": Implicit conversion from source type "dfloat" to result type "sfloat": Possible range/precision limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset and see if you get any other information......! otherwise one thing straight you can do is use Cast function to convert that to integer and process if the source is a DB, if it is a file read as is and change it in Transformer. hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, Thanks, I had already created table using SQL and I was using Truncate in my final table saving ODBC Connection. I deleted table using SQL and used CREATE instead in the job which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When checking operator: When binding output interface field "DRIVERS" to field "DRIVERS": Implicit conversion from source type "dfloat" to result type "sfloat": Possible range/precision limitation.

You have to learn to read APT/Torrent error messages, which is the company that originally created Datastage PX. It is say:

When checking operator  ===> As the compiler is pre-checking a stage

When binding ... "Drivers" ===> I'm looking at a stage in which you are assigning the input field "driver" to the output field "drivers"

Implicit conversion from source type "dfloat" to result type "sfloat":  ===> You've got a type mismatch

I believe you can tell datastage to compile even if you get warnings, but the real answer is to go back inside your job and figure out why you're sticking a dfloat (double precision) into an sfloat (single precision). It's likely that you need to specify how to get from dfloat to the sfloat using a transformer and a user specified rule for accuracy truncation.